# Mac版Sourcetreeの文字化けについて

Tags: git, 文字化け, sourcetree, shift-jis

Shift_JISで書かれたJavaのコードがSourcetreeで文字化けしていたので、下記サイトを参考に文字化けを解消しようとしました。

[Git / SourceTree で、Shift JIS ファイルの差分を文字化けなく表示する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/matsuoshi/items/c93a0b55df827a28514e)

結果、ファイルステータスの差分の部分は日本語になったのですが、履歴の部分は文字化けを起こしたままです。どうすれば日本語で表示されるのでしょうか。

2行目に「名称」、5行目に「法人」と書かれています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
ñºèÃ
ñ@êl

Comment: 文字化けした結果どのような表示になっているか、サンプルを記載することはできますか？その内容、化け方でどういったことが起こっているのか推測することができる場合があります。

Comment: リンク先の記事は、htmlがSJISの場合の説明になっています。html をjava に変えて、.gitattributes ファイルを作れば、リンク先のように動作します。

Comment: ほんとは、エンコードを自動判別できるdiff プログラムがあるといいのですが、Macには詳しくないので。

Comment: htmlをjavaに変えて行いましたが、ファイルステータスに表示されている部分は日本語になりますが、一度コミットした履歴の部分は文字化けを起こしたままです.